# Upgrade/Transition Path from MySQL Community 5.6.31 to Enterprise

Tags: mysql, upgrade, enterprise-edition

Full disclosure. I have never upgraded a database. I have a MySQL Community that is not the latest @5.6.31 ( latest is 8 ?) to the paid, Enterprise version. We will ask Tech Support once purchase of Enterprise is fully approved... but really trying to find a clear upgrade path online has proven difficult. I'm a novice, so feel free to be very details in replies.

Comment: Seems like [direct 5.6 to 8 is not supported](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrade-paths.html) - I'd wait and take advantage of the product support you're paying for.

Comment: like @LowlyDBA said i think the safe way is is to install MySQL 8 on a other directory leave the MySQL 5.6 as it is for now..  Make a .sql dump from the MySQL 5.6 and import it on MySQL 8.0.. Test/Compare the tables and data between MySQL 5.6 before removing MySQL 5.6..  This feels like the most safe way..

Comment: Once you’ve paid for Enterprise you can log a ticket with Oracle Support and they will walk you through it. As Rick James mentioned the upgrade path is to step onto each major release between your old and destination versions. The trick with upgrades is to ensure your application both works and provides an acceptable performance level for your users before you commit to the change. It’s hard/time consuming to rollback major upgrades when all your eggs are in one basket.

Answer (score 1):

1. Upgrade to 5.7.  Follow all the steps there, including testing `mysql_upgrade`.
2. Test your code against 5.7.
3. Then embark on upgrading from 5.7 to 8.0; it's more complex but still doable.